# java byte code in 64bit

Tags: java

I have looked over the instruction set for x86_64bit machine and try to match but unfortunately didn't get any solution. I don't want the exact answer, just asking if someone know the steps to solve this problem or if there are any tools to solve it.

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 3):

First of all, get that byte stream written to a file. That's a lot easier to work with than a string. There are many ways to solve that particular problem I just used what came first to mind (probably highly suboptimal):

> echo -n `echo ba000000004885ff74144889fa8b073b02480f4cd7488b7f084885ff75ef4889d0c3 | sed 's/(..)/\\x\1/g'` > f.bin

Now you can use various tools to disassemble the file:

e.g.

> ndisasm -b 64 f.bin

`-b` selects 64-bit default mode

or

> objdump -D -b binary -m i386:x86-64:intel f.bin

`-D` means disassemble all sections, `-b binary` specifies that the file is a binary file (rather than e.g. an object file), and `-m i386:x86-64:intel` selects 64-bit x86-64 decoding with intel syntax.

You can also look at an [opcode map](http://ref.x86asm.net/coder64.html) to decode the stream. Starting out we see `BA` which matches `B8+r` which is `MOV r16/32/64 imm16/32/64`. Since the instruction doesn't have a `REX` prefix it's the `r32 imm32` version. In this case is `r == 0xBA-0xB8 == 2`, looking at the "32/64-bit ModR/M Byte" table we see that `r` is `edx`. The immediate follows in the next 4 bytes (in this case it is 0). The instruction in other words decodes to:

```
mov edx, 0
```

The next instruction starts with a `REX.W` prefix (`48`) followed by `TEST r/m16/32/64  r16/32/64` (`85`). You should be able to decode the follow `ModR` byte on your own.

A final hint: You might want to look at `objdump`s `--adjust-vma` command line option.

Answer (score 0):

Use gdb.  You can define data bytes in a sequence, then use the disassembly operation.  Let me know if you need this answer expanded.

**EDIT**. Because this is homework, you should probably do it by hand.

The decoding tables at sandpile.org are pretty good.  Click on "one byte opcodes" to start.

Your machine language is:

```
ba000000004885ff74144889fa8b073b02480f4cd7488b7f084885ff75ef4889d0c3
```

so your first byte is `ba`.  Look that up in the table.  It says `MOV rDX,Iv (r10,Iv)`.  There is no REX prefix so it is a move into edx.  To understand the `I` and the `v`, go to http://www.sandpile.org/x86/opc_enc.htm.  Here we see the capital `I` means immediate and the lower case `v` is either a word or dword or qword.  As you are moving into edx you have a dword, so look at the next 8 bytes after the `ba`.  They are all zeros so your first instruction is `mov edx, 0`.  Painful, yes, but it's homework.  If you haven't covered the use of these decoding tables yet, then use the nice techniques presented in user786653's answer.

Comment: Thanks.. I never used gdb. It will be really helpful if you expand a little

Comment: Still working on forming a suitable executable at your provided offset. Sorry.

Comment: Oh, wait, just noticed it was homework.  I suspect you have to do this by hand.  I will update the answer accordingly.